# Lost preferences when upgrading Blender, how can I get them back?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges, shortcut

I downloaded the latest version, and I made a huge mistake and I did not copy the UI from the previous version.
Now the 123 keys change my camera and they do not select vertices, edges or faces.
Do you know how I could fix it or reassign it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the old version installed, you can still find the preferences saved. Go to: C:\Users\ <your username>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\ <old blender version>\config

Comment: And, if you delete the config of the new version, next time you open Blender you'll have the option to transfer settings from the old version.